# How to have a Heat Map of an irregular geometry with python?

Tags: datagrid, geometry, heatmap

Suppose that I have a geometry as below:

[image]]

I have all the coordinates (x,y) and the amplitude z for each point. I created a heat map interpolating all the points, but the hole was also considered.

I was wondering if is possible to build a heat map in the entire geometry (with a smooth image from interpolated data points which is not described by the mesh), excluidng the hole? It must appear in the heat map as hole (white hole).

Thanks in advance

I have tried the follow code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata


data = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', skiprows=4)
data = np.array(data)


x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]
z = data[:,2]

# define grid.
xi = np.linspace(np.min(x),np.max(x))
yi = np.linspace(np.min(y),np.max(y))

# grid the data.
zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='cubic')

# contour the gridded data, plotting dots at the randomly spaced data points.
CS = plt.contour(xi,yi,zi,15,linewidths=0.5,colors='k')
CS = plt.contourf(xi,yi,zi,15,cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.colorbar() # draw colorbar
```

And as a result I have:

[image: heat map]